# Unselect the select item in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action

First of all, I create txtfield at `_txtbtn`. then  i select the any mc and create the many listener on them. And now  I want to remove listener when I click on `_can`. So I created `_unselect` function. But it doesn't work as expected.

```
function _txtbtn(e:*):void
{
myText = new TextField();
mc3 = new MovieClip();
myText.text = "text...";
myText.type = "input";

mc3.addChild(myText);
addChild(mc3);
mc3.x = _can.x;
mc3.y =  p;
p = mc3.y + mc3.height + 10;
 this.mc3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,_select);


function _select(e:MouseEvent):void
{

tool_stage.combo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,_font);
tool_stage.steeper.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,_size);
tool_stage.italic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,_bold);
tool_stage.colPicker2.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeColor1);
_can.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,_unselect);
}

function _unselect(e:*){
mc3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,_select);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My gut is telling me that you may have registered more than one mouse down listeners to "mc3".  Without knowing the full scope of the code, I suggest that you add this following line before you add the mouse down listener to mc3.

```
// This is the new line, it is just to remove any prior event registrations just to be safe.
this.mc3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,_select);
//This is the original line of the code, leave it as is
this.mc3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,_select);
```